# Indice no válido numpy ndarray python

Tags: python, matrices

Estoy intentando operar con dos arrays de la siguiente manera:

```
for i in range(len(py)):
    if(i<len(py)-1 and py[i][8] > 0):
        if(py[i][0] == py[i+1][0] and py[i][1] >= 0):
             print(py[i-stockpy[i][1]][7])
```

> **IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices**

sin embargo al poner `print(i - stockpy[i][1])` , me permite hacerlo.

Comment: Hola, Sería más claro si añades una muestra de tus datos. Por ahora lo que podria generarte error es que al usar `stockpy[i][1]` estas usando 2 niveles de indexacion, que supongo tu dato los tiene y por eso te lo permite. Al usar `stockpy[i][1][7]` añades un nivel mas con el índice `7`, es eso lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: lo habia copiado mal, lo editadé  y es como está. lo que necesito es poder restarle al indice de PY  de la columna 7 lo que hay en stockp[i][7].

Comment: puedes postear el resultado de `np.shape(py)` y `np.shape(stockpy)`, despues de importar numpy? (`import numpy as np`)

Comment: py.shape
(556784, 10)    y stock.shape (556784, 2)

Comment: pasando en limpio, es muy simple, py[i - (un numero)][7] es solo eso lo que necesito, pero iterados porque para cada registro cambia el valor, pero si lo hago en el bucle no me funciona

Comment: Añade esto antes de tu print para imprimir el indice que estas intentando usar `print(i-stockpy[i][1])`. He intentado replicarlo pero por los valores que tengo no me imprime nada.

Comment: Probablemente `stockpy[i][1]` no sea un número, sino algún tipo de `nd.array()` o estructura de datos que, aunque te permite hacer la operación de restarselo a un entero `i`, no produce como resultado un entero que puedas usar como índice (aunque al imprimirlo sí que puede mostrártelo como entero, según a qué clase pertenezca ese resultado y cómo esté definida esa clase). Intenta `print(type(i - stockpy[i][1]))`. También es posible que el resultado sea `float`, que tampoco puede usarse como índice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno procedo a compartir la resolución. Muchas gracias por las recomendaciones

```
py[i - int(stockpy[i][1])][7]
```